Solid objects becoming transparent during Cycles render
I'm having an issue where some obejcts in my scene are becoming transparent during the render, but only when using my GPU. I have tried rendering with my CPU and have no issues with this happeneing.
I've had it happen in multiple renders with multiple models so it doesn't seem to be the model as the problem.
You can see the circled meshes have become transparent during the render.

Does anyone have any idea what it could be? All of my GPU drivers are up to date.

blend-exchange.com

ah my file is way too big to upload there unfortunately. Does anyone have any clue what it could be at all? It's a 280 frame render at 30fps.
No denoise
Motion Blur
Only happening with GPU using optix in system settings
Tried multiple materials to see if it was that but still getting the same issue
Applied transforms etc. to the object
